# The Jugs of Water Problem - with constraints

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Given three jugs containing any amount of water such that $a_1 \leq a_2 \leq a_3$ and each jug is large enough to contain all the water, show that it's possible (or not) to empty one jug.

Only allowed operation is:

> - Double the content of a jug by pouring water from another one.

This was actually easy to proof for the classic two-jugs problem but I am having trouble with this version. Any thoughts?

Comment: Assuming the "amounts" need to be integers, right?

Comment: I don't see how the two-jugs problem can be solved. For example, start with (8, 1). We get the sequence (7, 2); (5, 4); (1, 8) and we are back where we started.

Comment: @mjqxxxx Yes, integers.

Comment: @M.Wind For two jugs it's not always possible - that's the solution.

Comment: Two proofs that one of three jugs can always be emptied are provided in the book Mathematical Puzzles, A Connoisseur's Collection by Peter Winkler,AK Peters, 2004.